# varキーワードの使用頻度について

Tags: c#

今まで、ある程度変数の型がわかりにくい場合にはvarキーワードを使用せずに
型を明示して宣言していました。

しかし最近は全てのローカルスコープでvarを使用しています。

理由は以下です。

- 複数の変数宣言がある場合、可読性が高くなる場合がある。

  ```
  var i = 10;
  var s = "foo";
  var c = 'c';
  ```
- C#には右辺で型を明示できる場合が多い

  ```
  var a = new Foo();
  var b = default(Foo);
  ```
- 振る舞いがわかっていれば、具体的に型がわかっていなくとも問題ない場合がある

  ```
  var a = GetFoo();
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    a += i;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(a);
  ```

質問ですが、一般ではvarの乱用は避けるべきでしょうか？

Comment: 控える必要は無いに1票。
varを使っていて可読性が下がるのは、IDEを使っていない場合だと思います。
じゃあどこまでIDEを使っていない場合を考慮しなければならないか？ってだけじゃないですかね？
C#であればVisualStudioを利用している前提で良いと思うんだけどなぁ...

Comment: ありがとうございます！
今のままのスタイルで行きたいと思います。

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[C# のコーディング規則 (C# プログラミング ガイド)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ff926074.aspx)

> 暗黙的に型指定されるローカル変数
>
> - 変数の型が代入の右側から明らかである場合、または厳密な型が重要でない場合は、ローカル変数の暗黙の型指定を使用します。
> - 代入の右側から型が明らかではない場合は、var を使用しないでください。
> - 変数の型を指定するときに変数名に頼らないでください。 変数名が正しくない場合があります。
> - dynamic の代わりに var を使用しないようにしてください。

ローカルスコープ内で多用する分には全く問題ないと思われます。ローカルスコープが巨大である場合は別の問題があるので、それは除きます。

Comment: 大変参考になりましたっ！！
ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 4):

避ける必要は、ありません。
逆に必ず使わなくてはいけないというわけでもありません。

個人的見解としては、int、longなどの数値型の場合、varを使わないほうが良い場合があります。
それ以外、varを使用できるのであれば、varを使用すべきです。

Comment: 数値型...なるほど、参考にさせていただきます。
ありがとうございます！